# Azure logic apps REST API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-logic-apps, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to automatically deploy an azure logic app with a managed connector to MS To Do. The resourcegroup, the logic app itself and the api connection are deployed via Azure devops and to this point everything is working fine. I also wrote some Javascript Code for retrieving an access token for the api connection, but I'm failing at calling the REST API for the updating the API connection. I looked up the MS documentation and was able to do the `GET` request for the resource, but the documentation for updating a resource is utter crap and I just don't get how to do it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources

I think the URI is right, because like mentioned above, the `GET` request is working. Here's how it looks:

```
PATCH/PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/O365I-Deployment-Test/providers/microsoft.web/connections/to-do?api-version=2015-08-01-preview
```

I just don't know what the body of the request should look like to update the api connection's access token.

I know there is a powershell script out there that can establish the connection, but I would prefer to do it this way.

Comment: Do you want to update the access token for resource?

Answer (score 0):

The access and refresh tokens are not actually exposed via the ARM REST APIs to update in this manner. You can however fetch the consent links, open to authorize and [confirm the consent code](https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth/blob/master/LogicAppConnectionAuth.ps1#L73) acquired from the final redirect in the popup, which the powershell script showcases.

The [several ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-deploy-azure-resource-manager-templates#authorize-oauth-connections) to work around authorization are listed in the docs with the one requiring minimal setup is to re-use preauthorized connection resources, which works as long as they are in the same region as the logic app.